# The End of the Desert Sauce

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, geography

[image: The End of the Desert Sauce]

<sub>Transcript</sub>

```
Clues:

[map compass containing "19!"]

3336665555556669 84433 7777833255 777728822233
 8666 77773333 944666 933 64444448 2233

+---+---+---+---+---+ +---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7 | |   | 1 | 2 |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+ +---+---+---+---+---+

Instructions: Name That Comedy Duo

_ _ _ _ _ E _ _ _ _ D _ _ _ _
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the puzzle but my mobile phone underlines long digit sequences (treating them as phone numbers), which could "threaten an accident". Is there any way around this?

Comment: @happystar rot13(Hfr n zhygvgnc syvc cubar) 

Comment: Hint13: gur rkpynvzngvba cbvag zrnaf fbzrguvat fcrpvsvp va zngu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm quite sure we are looking for a british couple. Why? let's start:

Some answers were already given:

> 333666...  =  "FOLLOW THE STEAK SAUCE TO SEE WHO WE MIGHT BE".
>  19! = 121645100408832000

Let's countinue with the latter:

> 18 digits.. could we somehow interpret that as a coordinate?
>  Maybe if we split that up to 2x9 and add two decimal points?
>  121645100 -> 12.1645100
>  408832000 -> 40.8832000

> leads us to somewhere in ethiopia, afar region. At least we found a desert. Horray :) [image: google_maps]

> But hey, there's a A1 nearby. And since that is a quite popular brand for steak sauce, let us follow that sauce.. eh, road.

> We end up in Addis Ababa. Luckily we have to fill a 2x5 grid:
>
> ```
> +---+---+---+---+---+ +---+---+---+---+---+
> |   | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7 | |   | 1 | 2 |   |   |
> +---+---+---+---+---+ +---+---+---+---+---+
>   a   d   d   i   s     a   b   a   b   a
> ```

> With that we get "baddi_s". Might "baddies" fit?
>
>  Baddies... Somehow (beeing a german with a strong addiction to british humor) that reminded me at a sketch of two guys, asking themselfs "are we the baddies here?"

So I'm left with a last question - does my assumption fit?

> It does. =)
>
> ```
> _ _ _ _ _ E _ _ _ _ D _ _ _ _
> M I T C H E L L A N D W E B B
> ```

Therefore, I'll go with

> Mitchell and Webb
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell_and_Webb

additional link:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToKcmnrE5oY

Comment: ROT13(Lbh unir n crefvfgrag glcb va Nqqvf Nonon. Pbeerpgvat gung jvyy svk lbhe "orqqvrf")

Comment: @fljx: ROT13(Gunaxf sbe cbvagvat bhg! Gur "glcb" vf whfg gur glcvpny trezna sbez - ohg V fubhyq unir fher fghpx jvgu gur ratyvfu bar.)

Answer (score 4):

Very much a partial solution here with some bits of info I have deduced.

19! means

> 19 factorial, or `19 * 18 * 17 * ... * 3 * 2 * 1`, or `1.216451e+17`.

The rows of sequences of digits represent

> the use of a multi-tap text entry system to spell out "FOLLOW THE STEAK SAUCE TO SEE WHO WE MIGHT BE".

Now Google tells me that in the US,

> "steak sauce" is a thing in its own right (in the UK I was thinking peppercorn, or bearnaise, or mustard.... as types of sauces you would have on steak). And apparently there are three main brands: Lea & Perrins, A1, and Heinz 57.

Comment: I'll add to this some of the things I've tried as well: rot13(V'z cerggl fher gung gur fgrnx fnhpr ersreraprf gur frpbaq bs gur znva bcgvbaf, naq gung pyhrf n N1M26 pvcure. Gur bayl cynpr V gevrq gb hfr vg jnf gur ahzore va gur pbzcnff - f sbe fbhgu, ohg gura gung jbhyq becuna gur snpgbevny ... V nyfb gevrq ybbxvat ng anzrf bs inevbhf qrfregf naq qvqa'g ernyyl trg naljurer. Terng Onfva zngpurf gur gjb svir-pryy obkrf ba gur evtug, ohg ntnva, abg fher jurer gb tb.)

Comment: Hint13: gung snpgbevny ahzore arrqf gb or npphengr gb gur barf cynpr. gur envfrq rkcbarag jba'g jbex.

Answer (score -1):

Partial solution :
I think that the name of the comedy duo is

> Laurel and Hardy

> This is because the title  of Riddle is  desert sauce Also they make a movie with title: the sons of Desert
> 1. the number 19 may be can indicate the centenaury  of this comic duo work
> 2. the map compass may could be a massonic symbol also is correlate with this comedy duo

Comment: Any other evidence? I could say that the name of the comedy duo is obviously Columbus since he was the one who NAVIGATED to the West and the compass indicates NAVIGATION.

Comment: Your answer doesn't fit the template ( .....E....D....)